# How can I cast from object to the bean

Tags: java

I have a Created three class and want to cast from object to the userPerformanceDetail bean.

I am getting class cast exception.

First class that i have created is

```
    class UserDetail{
       int a;
       getter;
       setter;
    }
```

Second class is

```
    class UserPerformance{
      int b;
      getter;
      setter;
    }
```

and third class that uses above two classes and have getter and setter

```
    class UserPerformanceDetail{
      UserDetail userDetail;
      UserPerformance userPerformance;

      getter;
      setter;
    }
```

and in other class i have created method that returns List

So how can I get UserPerformanceDetail from List

can I do

```
    for(Object obj: list){

     UserPerformanceDetail  userPerformanceDetail  = (UserPerformanceDetail)obj

    }
```

above is giving class cast exception

I am getting class cast exception.

Comment: what is into list? put debug point and check

Comment: Can you include the code that is creating the list.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility to avoid `ClassCastException` is to use `instanceof`:

```
if (obj instanceof UserPerformanceDetail){
  UserPerformanceDetail  userPerformanceDetail  = (UserPerformanceDetail)obj;
}
```

Comment: if obj can be one of your three classes then you have to insert three if conditions for each one in your loop

Comment: I want to cast it to userPerformanceDetail. Am i doing correct ot i am wrong

Comment: you doing it correct with the additional if condition

Comment: then your obj is not of that class

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Object obj: list){
    if(obj instanceof UserPerformanceDetail) {
        UserPerformanceDetail  userPerformanceDetail  = (UserPerformanceDetail)obj
    }
}
```

The above code should do it. but it will only get you objects that are `UserPerformanceDetail`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of above problem. I checked my code and got that I have duplicate object "UserPerformanceDetail" when I deleted one and rerun the application I got the correct results